# Inner joining of huge data causing blacklist issue

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, hiveql

When i try to do a inner join of 3 or more tables of huge data i am getting below error.

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1093.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
Aborting TaskSet 12.0 because task 4 (partition 4)
cannot run anywhere due to node and executor blacklist.
Most recent failure:
Lost task 4.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 109, te-163l.de.net.com, executor 7): java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted
at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.refill(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:202)
at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.refill(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:228)
at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.read(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:157)
at org.apache.spark.io.ReadAheadInputStream$1.run(ReadAheadInputStream.java:168)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
Blacklisting behavior can be configured via spark.blacklist.*.

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1890)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2049)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2081)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2102)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2121)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2830)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2829)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I even tried setting the config properties of "spark.unsafe.sorter.spill.read.ahead.enabled",'false' still i am facing the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go read How to Ask. and stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: as you said you are joining 3 huge tables .... then first thing your cluster should have enough capacity to process those joins and the second thing is to tune your executor memory(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) and executor cores accordingly. try to see you, is it possible to broadcast smaller table ... so there are a lot of variations you can try ... but your problem statement is very abstract .. kindly mention your code and your efforts till now.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but for whomever needs it you cant try the config `"spark.blacklist.enabled,False"` to disable the blacklist or `"spark.blacklist.killBlacklistedExecutors, True"` to try to move to another executors when it's blacklisted